# Installing IIS 7.5 on Windows Server 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-7.5

I have installed the IIS Express 7.5 on Windows Server 2003 SP2 using [Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) But the Server is still running the IIS 6.0 when I run the IIS manager.
Later I have installed IIS 7 Manager manually from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=2299) but I got this error

> Could not connect to the specified computer.
>
> Details: Impossible to load the file or assembly 'Microsoft.web.Administration, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=###' or its dependencies. The specified file was not found.

Someone can tell me why or why what did I miss?

Answer (score 1):

IIS Express is a developer version of IIS. It started on demand, it will not run as a service and will only run a single website. Although it can run on W2K3 R2 it's not intended to replace IIS 6.0 and as you found out IIS 6.0 keeps running. IIS Express is basically just a simple application which you start to test a website / webapplication.